# Better way to save array / objects in PHP Laravel MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

What is the better practice for example I have a table of `Posts` and the post might contain many comments, is it better to create a `Comments` table and use a foreign ID or create a column of `comments` in the `Posts` table and save it as an array and cast it in the Model? It would be like an array of objects

```
[{"username":"user1","date":"25 February 2022 01:01PM","comment":"qwer"}]
```

```
    protected $casts = [
        'comments' => 'array',
    ];
```

Comment: Absolutely the first one. If you are not familiar with what the keyword "normalization" means regarding database, now would be a good time to go read up on that a bit.

Comment: You can always use a non-relational database like MongoDB if you want non-relational data

Answer (score 1):

depend on how you're gonna use the comments.

For example if you want to retrieve a post with only the count of the comments instead of their content, then you will need to put them in another table to make retrieving that info faster and effortless.

```
// for example
Post::withCount('comments')->get();
```

If every time you need a post, you also need its comments, then there is no reason to put them in another table. But you will be limiting yourself for future evolution without a heavy cost on performance because it would go against database normalization.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to create a `comments` table and `Comment` Model with relation between your existing `Post` model and `Comment` model.

In case comment will only be attached to Post you can define a one to many relationship

Here is the definition of the `Post` Model

```
class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the comments for the blog post.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

And here is the definition of `Comment`

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the comments for the blog post.
     */
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}
```

with this you must have a foreign key on the `comments` table named `post_id` which reference the `id` in the `posts` table.

With this relationship established you can get all comment for a given post by simple calling `$post->comments` or access post from comment by calling `$comment->post` You can learn more here [Eloquent: Relationship - One to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)